# Is there a way to get the runtime dependencies of only one specific dependency?

Tags: maven

I have a multi-module maven project. Some modules are dependencies of others, while a separate project [a commons repo] has modules that are dependencies in my main project.

I was able to create an intermediary module that would collect the runtime jars which I was able to pass along, but when I try to incorporate teh same code into a different module, it pulls ALL runtime jars, and not just of the specific dependency. Code below.

GroupID B is an external 'commons' project we use across multiple projects.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>B</groupId>
     <artifactId>B.artifact2</artifactId>
     <version>${B.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I was able to create a separate [intermediary] module with just B.artifact2 as the only dependency, and used the following code to pull the runtime jars into their own ${project.build.directory}/target folder

```
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>1</id>
    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
      <excludeGroupIds>com.google.code.findbugs,net.jcip</excludeGroupIds>
      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
```

that works perfectly [gets me the ~15 jars I need], but we don't want to use the intermediary module. I am trying to incorporate that into the main module [that the intermediary would be a dependency of], but I have no way of selecting only that SPECIFIC dependency to get the runtime jars, instead it pulls practically all runtime dependencies into the folder. That project looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>A</groupId>
        <artifactId>A.artifact</artifactId>
        <version>${A.version}</version>
        <classifier>dist</classifier>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>B</groupId>
        <artifactId>B.artifact1</artifactId>
        <version>${B.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>B</groupId>
        <artifactId>B.artifact2</artifactId>
        <version>${B.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have multiple dependencies in this module and using something as below will still pull in ALL runtime dependencies [~40 jars]

```
      <execution>
          <id>test</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
              <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
              <excludeGroupIds>A,C,D,com.google.code.findbugs,net.jcip</excludeGroupIds>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars</outputDirectory>
          </configuration>
      </execution>
```

If i try to limit it to B.artifact2, I get only the artifact from B.artifact2 and not the runtime jars / dependencies for it...

Am I forced to use the intermediary module and then use that as a dependency for the main module?

Comment: That you "copy (maven) dependenies" (during "package" with "copy-dependencies") ...is rather uncommon/"a smell"! 1. Why do you do it? ...please have a read on "maven dependencies (scope runtime)" and in particular "maven import pom"!;)... and going deeper into "maven assembly"...

Comment: But the title question: "Is there a way to get the runtime dependencies of only one specific dependency?" - Sounds "very feasible" with maven.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you started in the wrong direction by using `copy-dependencies` in the first place.

In Maven, you do not handle dependencies by copying them around, but instead, you define them in the dependencies section of the POM and pull them from a Maven repository.

In companies, you usually run a Nexus/Artifactory on a server and use it.

You can also use the Maven local repository if your projects are small and you are just one developer. In any case, do not try to copy dependencies from one project into another.